# Warning: oci_connect(): OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

**Error**

```
Warning: oci_connect(): OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed. There is something wrong with your system - please check that LD_LIBRARY_PATH includes the directory with Oracle Instant Client libraries in

Warning: oci_connect(): Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804
```

**apache php oracle install method**

**1. /etc/profile**

```
##################### oracle oci setting
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/19.6/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

**2. download oracle 19.6 instantclient  download / install**

```
https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html
download instantclient-basic-linux.x64-version.zip
download instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-version.zip
download instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-version.zip
unzip * 
mv instantclient_19_6/ /usr/lib/oracle/19.6
```

**3. ldconfig set**

```
echo '/usr/lib/oracle/19.6' > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf
ldconfig
```

**4. vi /etc/tnsnames.ora**

```
ORA_TEST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ip_address)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ip_address)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = ORA_TEST)
      (SERVER = dedicated)
    )
  )
```

**5. oracle connect test ==> succcess**

```
sqlplus test/test@ORA_TEST
```

**6. web server install**

```
yum -y install httpd httpd-devel mod_ssl
```

**7. php install**

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php56
yum --enablerepo=remi-php56 -y install php php-devel php-cli php-common php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-xml php-pear php-curl php-pecl-imagick php-oci8 php-soap
```

**8. PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8.so'**

```
ln -s /usr/lib/oracle/19.6/libclntsh.so.19.1 /lib64/libclntsh.so.19.1
ln -s /usr/lib/oracle/19.6/libnnz19.so /lib64/libnnz19.so
ln -s /usr/lib/oracle/19.6/libclntshcore.so.19.1 /lib64/libclntshcore.so.19.1
```

**9. phpinfo()**
[oci8 in phpinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7rlf.png)

**10. console php test ==> succcess**

```
php -r "oci_connect('test', 'test', 'ORA_TEST');"
```

**11. web site php code ==> fail**

```
$oracle = oci_connect('test' , 'test', 'ORA_TEST', "AL32UTF8");

Warning: oci_connect(): OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed. There is something wrong with your system - please check that LD_LIBRARY_PATH includes the directory with Oracle Instant Client libraries in

Warning: oci_connect(): Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804
```

**12. php -v, php -ri oci8**
[php -v, php --ri oci8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6aZk.png)

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question

Answer (score 1):

You are setting up a lot of things that don't need setting up. Read the [Instant Client installation instructions](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html#ic_x64_inst) again.

Let's take a look:

> export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/19.6

Never set ORACLE_HOME when using Oracle Instant Client.  It can lead to errors like ORA-1804 or other startup problems.

> export TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin

If you had a simpler install you wouldn't need to set this.  See the Instant Client installation instructions.

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/19.6/lib:$ORACLE_HOME/sdk:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Use `ldconfig` as shown in the installation instructions so you don't have to worry about setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH and making sure it passed through to Apache (a common problem with PHP - and one you are probably hitting).  And there are no libraries in the `sdk` directory so that definitely doesn't need to be there.

> export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/19.6/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

This is for macOS, which you are not running

> export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
>
> export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8

These could be useful.

> mkdir -p /usr/lib/oracle/19.6/bin /usr/lib/oracle/19.6/lib /usr/lib/oracle/19.6/network/admin
>
> ln -s libclntsh.so.19.6 libclntsh.so
>
> ln -s libocci.so.19.6 libocci.so
>
> [ . . . ]

This all seems very convoluted.  Why not just move the unzipped directory to somewhere like /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_6 and run `ldconfig` as shown in the instructions?  Then you don't need to make links, directories, copy files etc etc.

You could do worse that look at the install instructions in the PHP Dockerfiles at https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleLinuxDevelopers/oraclelinux7/php

Comment: "As above" is not going to let us identify a cause.  Please update your original question with exact details.

Answer (score 0):

Your web server is not configured correctly to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH for PHP. See this post for a similar example, and make sure you are setting the environment correctly for the web server runtime.

- https://community.oracle.com/thread/4081480?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: 8.attach  image oci8 in phpinfo
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7rlf.png

Comment: You need to define the env variables (TNS_ADMIN..) in the web server env.
See https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2020/05/18/Installation-of-Oracle-extensions-for-PHP

Comment: 11. attach image php -v, php -ri oci8  https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6aZk.png

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem.

Was permissions.

All the command-line tests work because they are run as root.

It doesn't work when website->php because that runs as apache.  Fix for me was to make sure that oracle client libs are accessable to non-root/non-oracle users.

Make sure you can access each element of LD_LIBRARY_PATH's path and libs

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34992132)

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue. Restarting Apache server resolved the issue.